# flexible engine CCE via terraform

Tags: terraform, cloud

I'm trying to create CCE cluster on our flexible engine cloud via Terraform and I'm getting below error?

```
 Enter a value: yes

flexibleengine_cce_cluster_v3.cluster_1: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating flexibleengine Cluster: Bad request with: [POST https://cce.eu-west-0.xxxxxxx.com/api/v3/projects/e9a2929c302d45cc80500bb9228aeae8/clusters], error message: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","code":400,"errorCode":"CCE.01400001","errorMessage":"Invalid request.","error_code":"CCE_CM.0004","error_msg":"Request is invalid","message":"Cluster spec is invalid","reason":"BadRequest"}
│ 
│   with flexibleengine_cce_cluster_v3.cluster_1,
│   on main.tf line 14, in resource "flexibleengine_cce_cluster_v3" "cluster_1":
│   14: resource "flexibleengine_cce_cluster_v3" "cluster_1" {
│
```

My **main.tf** file:

```
resource "flexibleengine_vpc_v1" "example_vpc" {
  name = "example-vpc"
  cidr = "192.168.0.0/16"
}

resource "flexibleengine_vpc_subnet_v1" "example_subnet" {
  name       = "example-vpc-subnet"
  cidr       = "192.168.0.0/24"
  gateway_ip = "192.168.0.1"
  vpc_id     = flexibleengine_vpc_v1.example_vpc.id
}

resource "flexibleengine_cce_cluster_v3" "cluster_1" {
  name                   = "cluster"
  cluster_type           = "VirtualMachine"
  container_network_type = "overlay_l2"
  authentication_mode    = "rbac"
  description            = "new cluster"
  cluster_version        = "v1.23"
  flavor_id              = "cc3.large.4"
  vpc_id                 = flexibleengine_vpc_v1.example_vpc.id
  subnet_id              = flexibleengine_vpc_subnet_v1.example_subnet.id
  kube_proxy_mode        = "ipvs"
  extend_param = {
    clusterAZ = "multi_az"
}

}
```

I'm using the official tutorial from terraform : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/FlexibleEngineCloud/flexibleengine/latest/docs/resources/cce_cluster_v3